# How do I tell my manager that his code review comment is wrong?

Tags: communication, united-states, software-development

Recently during code review, my direct supervisor wrote a comment suggesting a change on some code I submitted. Normally, that is not a problem (and I understand that is the very point of code reviews), but it turns out that his concern is based on incorrect information.

More specifically, he raised concerns over a certain language feature, and explained why that could be an issue - except that, in fact, the language does not work as he explained. This is supported by language documentation, and is not a formatting/standards issue.
(The language issue is about as complex to understand, simple to fix, and makes as much of a difference as a trailing comma in a C array. That is to say, this behavior has never been changed, it is not hard to grasp that the comma is *optional*, it is not an obscure concept, and it does absolutely nothing.  I'm keeping the exact issue a bit vague on purpose.)

My question, then, is how do I explain to him (if at all) that his idea of how the language works is incorrect? Being at least one or two decades junior to him, I don't want to come off as arrogant. I would normally have no problem with sucking it up and making the change (it's as easy as deleting a comma) - but I also feel like that goes against the spirit of a code review.

*Not a duplicate of [How do I tell a coworker he's wrong?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/how-do-i-tell-a-coworker-hes-wrong), since this is specifically about telling your seniors they are wrong.*.

Comment: If you have a process for rejecting comments made during code review, just follow that.

Comment: @LaconicDroid We do not - as I understand it, code reviews go through a process but are somewhat informal at the office.

Comment: @rkeet +1 for the "missed a changelog" point - this may be a recurring issue from an *earlier* version of the language that the supervisor recalls fighting with in the past, but has been patched/updated/fixed since he moved into management.  Not "What an idiot, you don't need to do that", but rather "don't worry, you *no longer* need to do that"

Comment: Maybe this should have a country tag? OP's username makes me think this might be Japan, where A) hierarchies are a lot more important and B) age is part of that and "_one or two decades_" make a _huge_ difference. _The gist_ of the answers will probably be the same, but we might have to put in an extraordinary amount of effort (from western perspective) into staying respectful to the senior. I myself think "_being honest is my sign of respect_", but that definitely comes from my culture instead of being universal.

Comment: The manager's comment may be intended to help the code conform to the code conventions. Many companies expect all their code to have spaces instead of tabs (or vice-versa), uncuddled else blocks, or semicolons in Javascript: changes that don't affect whether the code runs, but which are standardized for readability.

Comment: @GregEdelston Good point - mentioning that had not crossed my mind. It is not an issue of standards, so I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: The manager should be managing and not doing code reviews.

Comment: Just ask for a couple of minutes of their time, and start a conversation in a respectful way (whatever form that might take in your specific culture). Don't make a big deal out of it, and don't come in with the mindset that they'll make a big deal out of it. It's just a conversation. Just say what you have to say, leaving a possibility that you may be wrong, that you may have missed something, or that there are valid reasons for the comment that you aren't aware of, and ask for clarification/reassessment.

Comment: As someone often on the 'senior' side of these types of situations, i can say we still make mistakes, and as i review code from many languages might have confused a language specific detail, so just tell him, dont be rude, but just the facts and a good manager will just say thanks, sorry, and move on.

Comment: I'd ask the other code reviewer for an opinion.

Oh, you only have one reviewer? Not great.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but now I'm curious about the language feature.

Comment: @MCEmperor std::vector list initialization support for arbitrary types (i.e., braced-init-list support)

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Be humble.

> I'm a bit confused here. My understanding was that feature X [has property Y](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/). Is there something I'm missing here which means this doesn't work in this case?

Much better to start from the assumption that *you* are the one that is wrong, rather than the other way round. If you're wrong, you'll learn something; if you were in fact right, you've now taught your manager something in a non-confrontational way.

As an important aside, while you say this is different from [our other question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/how-do-i-tell-a-coworker-hes-wrong), it isn't really: you should be humble with your peers and with your juniors as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93136/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-kendall-how-do-i-tell-my-manager-that-his-code-re).

Comment: I find being obtuse to be annoying and passive aggressive. If you think it is wrong just say "I think it works this way, as stated in document X".

Comment: +1. Always a good approach to ask questions during review no matter the position of developer/reviewer.

Answer (score 24):

You can simply "ask for more clarity" and show willingness to change but subtly indicating that his concerns are not valid. An email to this effect may help:

> You have requested **following changes** in the code because of **so and so** reasons. However, my understanding of this language is that this problem will not occur because it instead works **this** way. I suppose I am missing something but could you please clarify or confirm that my understanding is wrong? If you have few minutes, I can show a demo of this and may be you can point out more specifically what your concerns are.

This way you will at least have a documented proof that you tried to correct him back. If he still insist, you can do whatever he requested and just hope it wont be a problem in the long run.

Comment: And when asking for clarity, provide a unit test demonstrating correctness of the feature you implemented.  Ask for the clarifying comment to be provide in a way that you can make the unit test more complete.

Answer (score 21):

In one of your comment you say:

> "it is trivial to conclude that the requested change has no effect"

Based on this, the easiest way forwards would be to keep the change and spend your energy on something more important.

Obviously this is only applicable if the change is indeed harmless.

Comment: Mmmmmm from experience this approach works better in real life, like the minutia in directions for hardboiling eggs or something, than software.  Innocuous changes are a way for codebases to start getting cluttered and difficult to manage.  Don't allow inert code to enter your codebase uncontested.

Comment: So, make the change, but leave the old code (commented out of course) with a comment that it was changed at request of <manager> etc.

Comment: @Mike That's virtually the worst solution imaginable: Passive aggressive *and* cluttering the code base with commented out code (that's against most sane coding styles).

Comment: Your boss may take this as an insult.  Can you do this without using the word "trivial"?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to rewrite code that have no effect on the output emitted by the compiler, but those changes may still have impacts on the code's quality or maintainability. I would take a statement like "it is trivial to conclude that the requested change has no effect" to be a sign of stubbornness or ignorance, unless it is accompanied by a more substantial justification.

Comment: Obviously I'm not suggesting that the OP should say "it is trivial to conclude that the requested change has no effect" to their boss. I'm repeating a statement from one of their comments here on stack exchange and suggesting that it points to a simpler way forward if they fear confrontation.

Comment: @user1717828: Would this approach leave any visible _change_ in the codebase? Where I work, we handle review comments _before_ we merge the work, so the version the manager didn't like would never show up in the history to confuse anyone at all.

Comment: If the change has "no effect" then the request is a stylistic one. That is an entirely valid request, especially if it is consistent with much the rest of the project's or company's code. **The last thing you want is a codebase with a lot of stylistic variations for how the same thing is accomplished.**

Comment: -1 ignoring comments/requests in code review kind of defeats the purpose of code review. But more so, I suspect most people would find rude.

Comment: @CooperBuckingham sorry to be blunt but did you read the proposed solution before voting it down? Your comment makes me think not.

Comment: Do you mean “implement the suggested comment” in your answer? “Keep the change” I assumed was odd phrasing or a sentence with a left out word, meant not make updates to the PR. I would rephrase to be clear if that’s not the case. Though I would still down vote a solution of make changes to a PR for no reason.

Comment: This is clearly the best answer. If it truly doesn't make a difference, there's no reason not to accept the proposed change. Just make the change and move on. (Certainly a "trailing comma in a C array", given as an example in the OP, would not be worth fighting over. If it's really that much of a non-issue, don't argue about it).

Answer (score 15):

If your manager gets this part of the language wrong, is it possible that other developers will also be confused by it? Bear in mind that maintainability by other people should be a goal. So: if this feature is confusing, there's an argument to be made for *not using it*.

With that in mind, you can go to your manager and -- being humble -- state that 
 you were surprised by his comment, and so you double-checked the documentation. It turns out that this feature *is* as you described, but you accept that it could be confusing, so you agree that you'll adopt his suggested clearer way to write the code.

Comment: I think all this overblown humility is unnecessary, but this answer mentions the comment that I was looking for. Just show the guy the documentation, ask if he interprets it the same way and if the code needs a comment so others won't wonder about the same thing. This situation comes up often when doing code reviews.

Comment: This is the point: it's something that someone could be tripped over. It could also merit to be documented (e.g note that we are leveraging feature X and so Y is not needed, like it would if we had gone for the Z approach). So next time you would have clear intent and rationale...

Comment: From the example given in the question, the boss is not actually "wrong" - they are requesting something that is *functionally unnecessary* but also not *harmful* and will make no difference in the compiled output.  Likely as not, they are requesting it because it *makes the operation of the code clearer*, or brings it into line with company written or traditional standards for the company's code.  Code that *unnecessarily* requires being an expert in language nuances to understand is not code that is *good* for real world use.

Answer (score 10):

I feel that [Philip Kendall answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/135688/91443) is incomplete and lacking some backup so that is why I decided to write my own.

I often struggle to make people understand that they said something false but here are some techniques that often works for me:

### Technique One

If someone makes an unsupported claim that I'm afraid is false, I ask them for backup. Like:

> Oh, this is interesting/disturbing/curious, do you have any source for that? I want to know more about it.

Then, I let them search and they will, hopefully, realize their mistake on their own. Since they are the one who realizes their mistake, they won't feel the shame that often comes with the fact of being corrected.

If this doesn't work, I use technique two.

### Technique Two

If the previous technique didn't work or isn't possible, I act confused and ask for clarification. This way, I'm showing that I'm open to the possibility of being wrong myself and that being wrong isn't such a big deal.

I usually start with some basic questions and then ask the more complex ones, like:

> **Me**: So, <*some basic question*>, right?
>
> **Other**: Yes
>
> **Me**: And, <*some other basic question*>, right?
>
> **Other**: Yes
>
> **Me**: So, knowing that, how could <*your real question*>?

Using this series of question allows you to be sure that you are on the same ground knowledge and that you don't have some misunderstanding somewhere.

When they answer your last question, if you are still not satisfied with their answer, you can ask follow up questions, like:

> I still don't understand. When I read *X*, I understand *Y*. Isn't that right?

You notice that, during the conversation, I keep blaming myself for the misunderstanding. By doing so, you are not pressuring the other to be right. Since you can acknowledge being wrong with no shame, they will be more at ease to do the same.

---

I use this technique often and, so far, it's the best I have. Note that, in my experience, heated arguments are really bad and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: Technique one is gold. It kind of imposes an "*I know that I know nothing*" posture to the other person (and often, to ourselves).

Comment: Just be aware that "why" is a challenge. If you can rephrase any of your questions to use "what" or "how" instead of "why", you may get even better results with people.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the need to be so indirect and "humble" about this.

You can make it pretty polite and simple and clear without coming across as arrogant:

*Manager:*

> If you overflow an integer in C, it's undefined behavior, so add a check for that.

*You:*

> I think unsigned overflow is guaranteed to wrap around in C? Only signed overflow is left undefined. (I see it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).)

This seems just fine as a first response to me. The only way I could see this coming off as arrogant is if you have a back-and-forth argument.

Comment: I think this response would be fine to a peer, and *maybe* a manager.

Comment: This is either a bad example, or an example of unwise thinking.  Unless you can demonstrate that the *operational result* of wrapping is still *useful to the business* or else will be *ignored anyway*, the boss has a point - you need to handle the overflow.  That they mis-stated the nature of the problem is far less important than that they noticed that there *is* a problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yeah don't focus too much on the example...

Comment: @Mehrdad I think this is right, but I agree that as a coder, my first reaction to your example is "Yeah, you should handle that". If you added a simple change like "... guaranteed to wrap around in C, which our intended use case XYZ won't be affected by because ABC", my programmer mental alarms wouldn't be on high alert reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a matter-of-fact Socratic approach that avoids the need to be either humble or accusatory:

> Hi *NameOfBoss*, about line **X** in function **Y**; I believe it might benefit from some additional clarification. Mind if we take a quick look?
>
> This comment states **A**. Meanwhile, this documentation here states **B**. On face value, these two statements *seem* to contradict each other. If this is intentional, I believe it would be prudent to document why **A** is correct in spite of **B**. As the author of comment **A**, can you help me with that?

Comment: On the plus side, this leaves open the possibility that the reviewer's change might actually be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it in two ways, depending on the supervisor.
If the supervisor is a tech person that works in the language you code in - I would contact them through an email with something along the lines of:

> During the last code review, you have commented part xyz of my code as invalid and it got me wondering if my knowledge of how it works was correct. I have checked against the
>   documentation and made a small demo application and it seems to work correctly - should I still make the change or keep it in the current version?

Do include links to the documentation about that code part and a small demo - most developers, both junior and senior, are eager to learn new things in the field they work in and there is always a chance that it was just an honest mistake of your supervisor. It also shows that you make sure the knowledge you use at work is correct, which is usually well received by supervisors, while not attacking the supervisor in any way.

If your supervisor does not work with the language you use (as some teams often use many different technologies and the supervisor has to learn them a little for the sake of code review), and as you mentioned it is not a big change, I would change the code and not address it further - trying to persuade that your version is correct and their knowledge is too small would probably create more tension and negative feelings between you and your supervisor, than it would create good language practices.

Comment: "It works in my demo application" is not a good sign that something is correct. You should always go from an actual specification.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Oh how I wish that a specification would always be fully correct (looking at you, MSDN). It's also why i mentioned both documentation/specification and a demo should be included - it lets the supervisor quickly check/debug the code without the need of them writing a demo themselves.

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks for the feedback. After additional review, I see conflict X in your recommendation, please help me understand if this conflict is not the case or I have misunderstood your feedback."

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that do the change is much easier, First you do the change and get it reviewed once again. At time of submitting the changed code for review once again you can simply ask that

> Hello Jim, I checked the documentation provided for language and my understanding of the feature X working in language is as like
>   this.

You can then provide a link to the documentation and ask him if what you understood from document is correct or not.

Comment: Have the discussion *before* re-submitting, otherwise you're just creating extra work for everyone.

Answer (score -10):

In reading some of these workplace problems, it brings back old memories where I worked in a SLC, UTAH company, in a manufacturing environment as a programmer.  In looking back on it, I burned a bridge which I should of NEVER let happen. It was a bridge that I had to cross many times before. My supervisor was known as the company drunk, but he knew his stuff. He had many problems, but that side of him, was none of my business in the first place.
But NEVER tell your immdiate supervisor that he/she is wrong. NEVER! And never in front of his peers or any of his/her supvervisors. That a strike or nail in your coffin. 
But before you runoff at the mouth on him/she being wrong, first take some extra time plus some extra effort(s) on your part and research it all the problems out where he/she 'might' be incorrect in full and provide alternate answers or solutions to solve the problem(s). Notice the careful wordings in the above statement???  Use words like "'might' be incorrect" NEVER 'Wrong'. Have supporting documents and answers to support your theories. After you've done your extra homework, set up a time to meet with your supervisor in a meeting form so that it fits his/hers' schedule, not yours! And go into that meeting with an attitude showing that you are workable, friendly, and happy and SHOW IT! One thing I learned with this past supervisor, he could read my attitude and body language and facial features and voice - know everything about me. And with all this effort and a meeting, you could either loose or win. 
As my father would say, your supervisor holds the future of your job within the company you work in. In a sense, you are at his/hers' mercy. Oh, one thing I forgot, DON'T raise for voice for anything!  Again, as I look back on this job, I could see places where the bridge was starting to burn. My job as a manufacturing programmer, is just like yours. All my work was reviewed by my supervisor period! And I recieved good marks and bad marks on my work and sometimes I was told to redo my programming work, and it was humbling!
So my advice to you as a from manufacturing environment programmer, It's up to you if you want the job, if you like the job and want to stay - it's up to you and your attitude plays a big part in your job. Remember, you are to make your supervisor look GOOD to everyone!!  Enough of my preaching...   Now enjoy your job.

Comment: You really should use newlines and avoid YELLING.

Comment: Also, and more importantly: It is not clear how this answers the question - it looks more like a related anecdote. Please edit and clarify how this answers the question.

Comment: And *more* importantly, I believe most people agree that code reviews are a place of conversation - which means the comments and concerns go both ways. Having code/changes/comments criticized is not, and *should* not, taken personally by most programmers.

Comment: I think this answer is the perfect example of written "style" and "format" of communication between any two people, but especially engineers...can sometimes matter as much as the content of the communication.